# Mapping index positions with key values in Swift dictionaries

Tags: json, swift

Based on my model I am able to
`print(crypto, name, price ?? 0.0, totalSupply ?? 0.0)`
`// BTC Bitcoin 7639.39 17070625.0`
`// ETH Ethereum 590.943 99826611.0`
`// all 99 currencies`

I am forced to print out all 99 currencies in the API. I want to be able to *cherry-pick* specific currencies.

Dictionary "1" corresponds to BTC and dictionary "1021" corresponds to ETH. These are **not** the same as the "id" keys however they have the same numeric values.

Is it better to just find the "id" element then use a condition that says if the key value pair `"id":1` or `"id":1027` is found print all values in that dictionary? Do I need to map? A simple condition?

The goal is to have control to pick **one** currency i.e. **ETH/1027** and print one line which will ultimately will be placed in some kind of table later on.
`BTC | Bitcoin | 7639.39 | 17070625.0`

Controller

```
for (crypto, base) in rawResponse.data {
                    if let name = base.name {
                        let price = base.quotes["USD"]?.price
                        let totalSupply = base.totalSupply
                        print(crypto, name, price ?? 0.0, totalSupply ?? 0.0)   
                    }

                }
```

JSON Model

```
struct RawServerResponse : Codable {
var data = [String:Base]()

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case data
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let baseDictionary = try container.decode([String:Base].self, forKey: .data)
    baseDictionary.forEach { data[$0.1.symbol] = $0.1 }
}
}

struct Base : Codable {
let name : String?
let symbol : String
let quotes : [String: Quotes]
}

struct Quotes : Codable {
let price : Double?
let volume24H : Double?
}
```

JSON

```
"data": {
    "1": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
        "rank": 1, 
        "circulating_supply": 17069825.0, 
        "total_supply": 17069825.0, 
        "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 7663.22, 
                "volume_24h": 4898370000.0, 
                "market_cap": 130809824337.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": 2.1, 
                "percent_change_24h": 1.17, 
                "percent_change_7d": 2.17
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1527925172
    }, 
    "1027": {
        "id": 1027, 
        "name": "Ethereum", 
        "symbol": "ETH", 
        "website_slug": "ethereum", 
        "rank": 2, 
        "circulating_supply": 99817109.0, 
        "total_supply": 99817109.0, 
        "max_supply": null, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 589.299, 
                "volume_24h": 1841640000.0, 
                "market_cap": 58822122295.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": 1.9, 
                "percent_change_24h": 0.93, 
                "percent_change_7d": -0.96
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd actually advise you to use a different API, as this response format doesn't really look development friendly. However, if you have to use it, here's a quick fix you can do to pick a single item:

```
if let eth = data.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
    guard let crypto = item.value as? Base else {
        return false
    }
    return crypto.symbol == "ETH"
}).first {
    print(eth)
}

if let btc = data.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
    guard let crypto = item.value as? Base else {
        return false
    }
    return crypto.symbol == "BTC"
}).first {
    print(btc)
}
```

Comment: The answer was based on your snippet of code (titled **JSON Model**) so I assume the `data` is a reference to `[String : Base]` instance where `Base` is the `struct` you defined in the same code snippet

Comment: Code works nicely. Thank you. Is it possible to add a line in the same block that would allow me to select just a single value of that currency? i.e. just the *price*. Obviously I could just comment out values from the Base struct but that's cheating. I tried extending `let cryptocurrency = item.value` to `let cryptocurrency = item.value.name` but then I would get `Value of type 'String?' has no member 'id'` errors.

Comment: It is possible to it the way you suggested but then you'd have to compare the field that you extracted. For example, in your example of `let cryptocurrency = item.value to let cryptocurrency = item.value.name` you'd have to compare the following `return cryptocurrency == "Ethereum"` and conversely `return cryptocurrency == "Bitcoin"`

Comment: ok so what is the normal way since I'm using Codable, to pull just 1 value of 1 key? i.e. only the price of ETH. All the examples either pull multiples values of 1 key or 1 value of all keys.